# Transaction across changes in multiple tables

Tags: transactions, datagrip

In DataGrip, I made multiple changes in multiple tables in my database by clicking around with the mouse. I would like to commit all those changes in a single transaction. The `Tx: Manual` setting on top seems to only commit changes in a transaction from the one table that is on my screen. Is there a better way of achieving this than copying all the changes I did in a script, and then add `begin` and `end` and execute the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work if you turn on *Single Session Mode* in data source settings:

[image]